# OS X, Chrome, bug with position fixed and transform properties

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I have a problem. In one page I have element with position fixed and some background, and another element with transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
In fixed element a have a bug (look screen). How I should fix it? Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaQQyZ

```
.fixed{
    background-color: #6b322f;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 25px 5px 25px 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: left 300ms ease-in-out;
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 111111;}
.transform{
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In fixed element there is 2 colors on background instead uniform background (you can see it on screen)